# VB.net - Pass Custom Parameter in SQL Update Command

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, code-behind, sqldatasource

I am using a Gridview with SQLDataSource Select/Insert/Update command. It works fine for updating or changing value using the Gridview. However recently I added another plugin which use Javascript to retrieve data and I need that retrieve data to be the source data of the SQL. Any way I can do this?

Something like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <input type="hidden" id="newname" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID_AM" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StaffID" HeaderText="StaffID" SortExpression="StaffID" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
         SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [Name], [StaffID] FROM [Record]"        
         ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
         UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Record] SET [Name] = @Name, [StaffID] = @StaffID WHERE [ID] = @original_ID AND (([Name] = @original_Name) OR ([Name] IS NULL AND @original_Name IS NULL)) AND (([StaffID] = @original_StaffID) OR ([StaffID] IS NULL AND @original_StaffID IS NULL))">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="StaffID" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_StaffID" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
</form>
```

When I use the Gridview to update row, the plugin will generate a new name and store in the hidden input "newname.value". How can I put this value into the update parameter?

I am thinking a few ways to do:

- Find some way so that the SQL Parameter will somehow take that value
- Override the update command using the normal SQL update. But I want to keep the optimistic concurrency feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer. Later I find a more straight forward method, seems easier and seems work for my case.

I just add the parameters on the updating event:

```
Protected Sub SQL_Update(source As Object, e As SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs) Handles SqlDataSource.Updating

    dim staffid as string = newname.valie
    // presudo for other passing values

    e.Command.Parameters("@StaffID").Value = staffid
    //and for other parameters

End Sub
```

It can then adding those custom parameter before executing the SQL update

Answer (score 0):

You are using asp.net webforms I assume, that being said there is no (easy) way to make the server side asp.net datasource interface with the client side javascript, without writing your own asp.net control based off of the javascript plugin.

That being said, the easiest way that I found was using webmethods.  If you prefer using Jquery see this [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx).  If you want asp.net to do the heavy lifting see [this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/calling-an-Asp-Net-C-Sharp-method-web-method-using-javascript/).  I prefer link 2, so here is the jist:

First, you will need to add a scriptManager to your page, which will "write" javascript functions to make asynchronous calls to the server-side webmethods, this will be in your aspx file:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function HandleIT() {
            var name = document.getElementById('<%=txtname.ClientID %>').value;
            var address = document.getElementById('<%=txtaddress.ClientID %>').value;
            PageMethods.ProcessIT(name, address, onSucess, onError); 
            function onSucess(result) {
                alert(result);
            }
            function onError(result) {
                alert('Something wrong.');
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<div>
        <p>Say bye-bey to Postbacks.</p>

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtaddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCreateAccount" runat="server" Text="Signup" OnClientClick="HandleIT(); return false;" />
    </div>
```

And here is the webmethod, (this will be in your .aspx.vb file):

```
Imports System.Web.Services
<WebMethod> _
Public Shared Function ProcessIT(name As String, address As String) As String
    Dim result As String = (Convert.ToString((Convert.ToString("Welcome Mr. ") & name) + ". Your address is '") & address) + "'."
    Return result
End Function
```

You could make a webmethod for each sql query but even then I don't think you can reference those SqlDataSource objects.  You will need to use a different way to pull data with vb.net and then return that data from the webmethod.

Webmethods use JSON to send and receive objects, meaning they serialize and deserialize objects to and from JSON for you.  The object type I found that was most compatible to return to javascript was list(of dictionary(of string, object))) so your JSON would look like this:

```
[{"ID": 6, "Name":"sec0ndHand","StaffId" : "employeeOfTheMonth1"},{"ID": 3, "Name":"Tomy","StaffId" : "notEmployeeOfTheMonth1"}]
```

so your webmethod would look something like this in the end:

```
<WebMethod> _
Public Shared Function ProcessIT(name As String, address As String) As list(of dictionary(of string, object)))
    Dim result As list(of dictionary(of string, object))) = New list(of dictionary(of string, object)))
    'get/update/delete/insert your data

    'convert your return object into list(of dictionary(of string, object)))
    Return result
End Function
```